# Move files from a remote ftp server to a local

Tags: file-transfer, wget, ftps

I need to pull files from an ftp server regularly and have found that I can get the files easily enough using wget

```
wget -m --user=yyy --password=xxxx ftps://host.com.au
```

and that works really nicely. The problem is, it obviously leaves the files behind on the remote server and the next time I run the script, it gets them all again.

I saw that wget has a --delete-after flag, which on first glance would seem to be ideal, but, as the man page says, it only deletes local files not remote ones.

Is there a way to achieve this end? It needs to be via ftp unfortunately as I don't have shell access or rsync access to the remote server. Should I be looking at something other than wget?

Comment: Why are you using wget instead of an ftp client, which would be more likely to have this feature?

Comment: Good question. I can use filzilla or some such to achieve the outcome I'm after, but, I need to be able to script this so that I can run it from cron each day.

Comment: Have you consider using `lftp`?

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov can you please change your comment to an answer.  I'ts 90% working so I should give you the benefit of status :)  

All I need to work out is how to have mirror leave the remote directories intact and just remove the files

lftp ftp://site.com --user PW --password blah -e "mirror --Remove-source-files --verbose; bye"

removes files and directories when its done transferring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `wget` you can try `lftp`. Command like:

```
 lftp site.com --user <username> --password <password> -e "mirror --Remove-source-files -v
```

in this command `-e "mirror` is used to do a mirror or remote site

`--Remove-source` remove the source files after download. Be very careful with this command

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As I said in the comment above, --Remove-source does remove the source files which is great, but it also removes the directories in the entire directory tree which is not really what I want it to do, just remove the .csv files in the various directories.